# View Results of SELECT * INTO statement within PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am pushing data into a table that I created in PL/SQL and I have two questions.
I created an oversimplified example to illustrate using emp table located in following link:
https://apexplained.wordpress.com/2013/04/20/the-emp-and-dept-tables-in-oracle/

I created two queries within fetch statements (one that returns 6 rows and one that returns 2 rows).

1. How can I view results of table?
2. How can I write my PL/SQL code so that new data gets pushed to end of table and does not delete everything inside Table.

**Begin PL/SQL Code**

```
DECLARE
   TYPE EmpTabTyp IS TABLE OF EMP%ROWTYPE
   INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

   CURSOR FetchCursor1 is
    select * from emp where empno > 7800;

  CURSOR FetchCursor2 is
    select * from emp where empno < 7500;

   emp_tab EmpTabTyp;
BEGIN
   /* Retrieve employee record. */
   OPEN FetchCursor1;
   FETCH FetchCursor1
        bulk collect into Emp_Tab;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Size of Emp_Tab is ' || EMP_TAB.COUNT);
   close FetchCursor1;
   for indx in 1 .. EMP_TAB.COUNT
   loop
    dbms_output.put_line(indx);
    --The row below is giving error.
    --dbms_output.put_line(EMP_TAB.EMPNO||chr(9)||chr(9)||EMP.ENAME);
   end loop;

   OPEN FetchCursor2;
   FETCH FetchCursor2
        bulk collect into Emp_Tab;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(EMP_TAB.COUNT);
   --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(||EMP_TAB.empno||);
   close FetchCursor2;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Size of Emp_Tab is ' || EMP_TAB.COUNT);

   for indx in 1 .. EMP_TAB.COUNT
   loop
    dbms_output.put_line(indx);
    --dbms_output.put_line(EMP_TAB.EMPNO||chr(9)||chr(9)||EMP.ENAME);
   end loop;
END;
```

**End PL/SQL Code**

When I try to run following statement:

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(||EMP_TAB.empno||);
```

I get this error:

> Error report:
>   ORA-06550: line 37, column 34:
>   PLS-00302: component 'EMPNO' must be declared
>   ORA-06550: line 37, column 5:
>   PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>   *Action:

Here is output code when it runs successfully:

> anonymous block completed
>   Size of Emp_Tab is 6
>   1
>   2
>   3
>   4
>   5
>   6
>   2
>   Size of Emp_Tab is 2
>   1
>   2

Comment: `EMP_TAB` is a collection, which will have row members and each row member will have columns (attributes) like `EMPNO` or `EMPName` etc. To access individual rows you must use `EMP_TAB(indx)` and to access `empno` of first record, you must use `EMP_TAB(indx).EMPNO`. refer https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/bulk-binds-and-record-processing-9i for more examples

Answer (score 0):

`EMP_TAB` will be collection of rows fetched by cursor. To refer individual rows you must you `EMP_TAB(n)` which indicates nth record in your result set. To select empno of nth record, correct syntax is `EMP_TAB(n).EMPNO`

So correct usage in your case would be

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(||EMP_TAB(indx).empno||);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering question about how to print to dbms!

Comment: Hello, The responses above show how to print line using dbms_output.put_line.  How about if I want to add new rows to existing collection of rows.  Note that first query returns 6 rows and second query returns 2 rows.  I would like collection of rows (emp_tab) to have 8 rows after second fetch

Comment: @PatStarks You can solve problem in 2 ways. One method is to make a single cursor combining both queries using `UNION` or `UNION ALL` operator and bulk fetch result set to collection at once. alternate solution is to fetch result of second cursor into another collection and then use MULTISET UNION to combine both collections. See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/o53plsql-083350.html for example.

Comment: you can also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328389/pl-sql-caching-two-resultsets-into-collections-and-joining-them-together for better examples

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 DECLARE
       TYPE EmpTabTyp IS TABLE OF EMP%ROWTYPE
       INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

       CURSOR FetchCursor1 is
        select * from emp where empno > 7800;

      CURSOR FetchCursor2 is
        select * from emp where empno < 7500;

       emp_tab EmpTabTyp;
    BEGIN
       /* Retrieve employee record. */
       OPEN FetchCursor1;
       FETCH FetchCursor1
            bulk collect into Emp_Tab;
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Size of Emp_Tab is ' || EMP_TAB.COUNT);
       close FetchCursor1;
       for indx in 1 .. EMP_TAB.COUNT
       loop
        dbms_output.put_line(indx);
        --The row below is giving error.
        dbms_output.put_line(EMP_TAB(indx).EMPNO||chr(9)||chr(9)||EMP_TAB(indx).ENAME);
       end loop;

       OPEN FetchCursor2;
       FETCH FetchCursor2
            bulk collect into Emp_Tab;
       close FetchCursor2;

       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Size of Emp_Tab is ' || EMP_TAB.COUNT);

       for indx in 1 .. EMP_TAB.COUNT
       loop
        dbms_output.put_line(indx);
        dbms_output.put_line(EMP_TAB(indx).EMPNO||chr(9)||chr(9)||EMP_TAB(indx).ENAME);
       end loop;
    END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to add "DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(||EMP_TAB(indx).empno||);"

Answer (score 0):

> Hello, The responses above show how to print line using
>   dbms_output.put_line. How about if I want to add new rows to existing
>   collection of rows. Note that first query returns 6 rows and second
>   query returns 2 rows. I would like collection of rows (emp_tab) to
>   have 8 rows after second fetch

You can't simply add the data to the collection.
You can, however, do a BULK COLLECT into a separate collection and then combine the collections . You really need a nested table rather than an associative array. See example below:

```
DECLARE
   TYPE EmpTabTyp IS TABLE OF EMPLOYEE%ROWTYPE ;
      --INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

   CURSOR FetchCursor1
   IS
      SELECT *
        FROM EMPLOYEE
       WHERE EMPLOYEE_id > 4;

   CURSOR FetchCursor2
   IS
      SELECT *
        FROM EMPLOYEE
       WHERE EMPLOYEE_id < 3;

   emp_tab   EmpTabTyp;
   emp_tab1   EmpTabTyp;
BEGIN
   /* Retrieve employee record. */
   OPEN FetchCursor1;

   FETCH FetchCursor1 BULK COLLECT INTO Emp_Tab;

   CLOSE FetchCursor1;


   OPEN FetchCursor2;

     FETCH FetchCursor2 BULK COLLECT INTO emp_tab1;

   CLOSE FetchCursor2;  
   --Joining two collections
   Emp_Tab := Emp_Tab MULTISET UNION  Emp_Tab1;

   FOR indx IN 1 .. EMP_TAB.COUNT
   LOOP      
      dbms_output.put_line(EMP_TAB(indx).EMPloyee_id||chr(9)||chr(9)||EMP_TAB(indx).First_NAME);
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Output:

```
sql > 
9               XING
1               Dan
2               Helen

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Many thanks!  This is what I am looking for.  My real life example is more complicated because I will concatenate the results of many queries to a single collection.  I shall try that using what I learned from this useful post!